# How to solve "there is already an open datareader associated with this connection"

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

The main problem is that when the web app is launched to the internet, when the load is high an exception is raised telling that there is already an opened data reader.

The following are the specs we use:

- Entityframework 5.0.0
- MySQL database

Is there a way of solving this problem without the `using(){}` block? Main problem of this approach is that when closed the using block I can't expand foreign key relations of entityframework objects inside the html view.

I also attach some source code, showing how we keep a single database context through the whole application

```
public abstract class AbstractService
{
    public Entities db_model
    {
        get
        {
            return DbContext.Instance.db_model;
        }
    }
}

public class DbContext
{
    public Entities db_model = new Entities();
    private static DbContext _dbContext;

    public static DbContext Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_dbContext == null)
            {
                _dbContext = new DbContext();
            }
            return _dbContext;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a static context!

Comment: @GertArnold Okey then how do I obtain the same context from different parts of the application??

Comment: Just don't. Context per request is the recommended pattern for web apps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22there+is+already+an+open+datareader+associated+with+this+connection%E2%80%9D+%5Bentity-framework%5D+hasaccepted&mixed=0

Comment: *can't expand foreign key relations of entityframework objects inside the html view* -- I strongly recommend that you don't use Entity Framework objects in an ASP.NET View.   Instead, try copying all the individual fields data into a new object (View model) instead.   This will keep a clean separation between your "data" layer and your "view" layer by using separate models.      This way you can use a DbContext properly within a `using` block.   It's common to copy all of the view data into completely separate classes.

Comment: @BenCottrell would it be something similar to using DTOs? If so do you have any code snippet to show your point?

Comment: @JuanAzaGutierrez Exactly that, yes.   There's also  the need to use `.Include()` to load related data within the `using` block.     Would these pages give you enough to work with?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data and   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5  -- you could do the mapping 'by-hand' or use AutoMapper - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613779/cleanest-way-to-map-entity-to-dto-with-linq-select

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specifically related to the issue mentioned in the question about using the loaded entities in an ASP.NET View.    The question asks about a way of solving this problem without a `using` block or disposing of the `DbContext`, however I am suggesting doing exactly this.

The reason being that it's generally desirable not to use Entity Framework objects in the ASP.NET Views because those objects are a lot more more than just plain POCO objects; they hide logic which allows them to act as a proxy to the underlying database, so they have a hidden dependency on the state of the `DbContext` which created them.

Here's a contrived example using EF models for `Employee` and `Department` with a `DbContext`:

```
public class CompanyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

If these were used in an ASP.NET application, I would create some separate models which aren't tied to Entity Framework, to be used by ASP.NET.   For example:

```
public class DepartmentModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeModel> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

A few considerations:

1. According to the MSDN docs, *"A `DbContext` represents a combination of the UnitOfWork and Repository patterns"* - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0 - Therefore the `DbContext` should be short lived as far as possible.
2. When loading data from the context, related entities can be retrieved using `DbSet<>.Include()`  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data
3. Generally speaking, it makes sense to de-couple the 'data' layer from the 'view' layer - for all kinds of reasons, some of which are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5 -- this involves mapping between the EF objects and the POCO Models.

The logic which is used to query the `DbContext` would query the data using EF, and return that data using POCO models so that only logic which deals directly with `DbContext` has any involvement with the EF objects.    For example:

```
    public List<DepartmentModel> GetAllDepartments()
    {
        using (var ctx = new CompanyDbContext())
        {
            // Ensure that related data is loaded
            var departments = ctx.Departments
                .Include(d => d.Employees);

            // Manual mapping by converting into a new set of models to be used by the Views
            var models = departments
                .Select(d => new DepartmentModel
                {
                    Id = d.Id,
                    Employees = d.Employees
                             .Select(e => new EmployeeModel
                             {
                                 Id = e.Id,
                                 DepartmentId = e.DepartmentId
                             })
                             .ToList(),
                })
                .ToList();

            return models;
        }
    }
```

Being able to use those POCO models, while requiring some extra boilerplate code, provides complete separation between the `DbContext` and ASP.NET, allowing the data to be used without ASP.NET Views/Controllers being concerned by the lifetime or state of the `DbContext`.

Sometimes this may look as if this approach violates the 'DRY' principle, however I would point out that EF objects and ViewModel objects exist to solve different problems, and it's not uncommon for the ViewModel objects to take a different shape, or even to require additional fields/attributes which wouldn't be suitable to add to the EF classes.

Lastly, the above uses 'manual' mapping, but if the mappings are really simple and straightforward, then it could make more sense to use AutoMapper instead:   [Cleanest Way To Map Entity To DTO With Linq Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613779/cleanest-way-to-map-entity-to-dto-with-linq-select)